# Set grid layout properly

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I need to structure the `radio buttons` as shown below.

**image 1**

[image]

I have tried as shown below.

**.html**

```
<ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
         <ion-grid radio-group formControlName="location">
             <ion-row>
                 <ion-col col-12>
                    <ion-item *ngFor="let l of locations;let index = index">
                         <ion-label class="custom-radio">
                             <ion-radio value="{{index}}"></ion-radio>
                                <i class="{{l.icon}}"></i><br/> {{l.description}}
                         </ion-label>
                    </ion-item>
                 </ion-col>
             </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
      </ion-col>

  <ion-col col-6>
    //other part           
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Then it looks like below.

[image]

Can you tell me how to design it looks like `image 1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can post your HTML and CSS, then I'd be happy to help with your actual code. However, in principle, you can do something like this;

**HTML**

```
<div class="ion-item">
    <i class="l-icon"></i>
    <span class="l-description">Text below the image</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ion-item {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}
.l-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.l-description {
    display: block;
}
```